# MFC Add thin border to WS_CHILD window

Tags: mfc, dialog, childwindow

How can I add border to an embedded child window with (`WS_CHILD | DS_CONTROL`) style hosed by a `CFormView`?

I have tried to add border in Dialog Editor by selecting `Thin` border type but it doesn't work.

I also tried `SetWindowLong` and `ModifyStyle`. But the result is, WS_BORDER style is added but still no border.

Is it possible to add border to embedded child window by choosing styles? or should I draw it myself?

Thanks,
Guan

Comment: From [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx): *"Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using **SetWindowLongPtr** will not take effect until you call the [**SetWindowPos**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) function."* Passing `SWP_DRAWFRAME` to [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) is required.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you! I change my code to `ModifyStyle(0, WS_BORDER, SWP_DRAWFRAME)` and it works now. (`SetWindowPos` is internally called by `ModifyStyle`).

Comment: You should write that up as an answer then. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in case you are wondering, if this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

As @IInspectable points out, passing `SWP_DRAWFRAME` to `SetWindowPos` is required after changing the window styles.

I finally choose `ModifyStyle` to add `WS_BORDER` to my `WS_CHILD` window and pass `SWP_DRAWFRAME` flag to the third parameter: `m_wndMainPage.ModifyStyle(0, WS_BORDER, SWP_DRAWFRAME)`. It internally calls `SetWindowPos` and update the child window. Window border is drawn as expected.